# Spherical Coordinates ( plane y = -x)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I am attempting to express the plane y = -x in spherical coordinates. Is there any clean way to do this?

I have expressions for rho, theta, and phi in my text book but I don't think anyone of those would work.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\tan\phi = \frac{y}{x}$ the equation is $$\phi = -\frac{\pi}{4} \bigcup
\phi = \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply Mark. Does this account for the negative region when y is less than 0, and x is greater than zero?

Comment: That's where the union symbol comes into play. It's connecting both half-planes, the one given by $-\pi/4$ and the other given by $3\pi/4$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand Mark's logic, but my professor disagreed.